# Status of JSR/RET in JVM spec

Tags: java, jvm, opcode, finally, jvm-bytecode

There are some parts of the JVM specification which suggest that the operations [JSR (Jump SubRoutine)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.jsr), [JSR_W (Jump SubRoutine Wide)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.jsr_w) and [RET (RETurn from subroutine)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ret) may be used only up to class file version 50.0 (JDK 1.6):

> [**3.13 Compiling Finally**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13)
>
> (This section assumes a compiler generates class files with version number 50.0 or below, so that the jsr instruction may be used. See also [§4.10.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.5).)

And later:

> [**4.10.2.5. Exceptions and `finally`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.5)
>
> To implement the `try`-`finally` construct, a compiler for the Java programming language that generates `class` files with version number 50.0 or below may use the exception-handling facilities together with two special instructions: *jsr* ("jump to subroutine") and *ret* ("return from subroutine").

On the other hand, the opcode descriptions themselves say nothing about a deprecation of these features. And the quoted texts only say how things used to be in versions up to 50.0, but doesn't explicitely state the state of affairs after that.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871190/why-are-jsr-ret-deprecated-java-bytecode#comment48074067_5871190) (to a question which asks about the motivation behind this deprecation or removal) indicates a similar level of confusion, so apparently I'm not the only one looking for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While adding links to my question, I noticed that the opcodes in question are absent from [**§4.10.1.9: Type Checking Instructions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9). So this shows that the new strackframe-based type verification scheme can't handle them, and [**§4.10: Verification of class Files**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10) writes:

> Verification by type checking must be used to verify `class` files whose version number is greater than or equal to 50.0.

Or in more detail in [**§4.10.1: Verification by Type Checking**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1):

> A `class` file whose version number is 50.0 or above ([§4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1)) must be verified using the type checking rules given in this section.
>
> If, and only if, a `class` file's version number equals 50.0, then if the type checking fails, a Java Virtual Machine implementation may choose to attempt to perform verification by type inference ([§4.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2)).

So I'd say a version 50.0 class *may* still contain *jsr* and *ret*, but runs some risk that a JVM implementation won't verify said class and as a consequence will fail loading it.

But then I found an even more explicit rule, in [**§4.9.1: Static Constraints**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.1):

> Only instances of the instructions documented in [§6.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5) may appear in the `code` array. Instances of instructions using the reserved opcodes ([§6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.2)) or any opcodes not documented in this specification must not appear in the `code` array.
>
> If the `class` file version number is 51.0 or above, then neither the *jsr* opcode or the *jsr_w* opcode may appear in the `code` array.

The first paragraph is irrelevant for this question, since the instructions are listed in §6.5, and are not reserved according to §6.2. But the second paragraph explicitely marks them as forbidden in version 51.0 and up. The *ret* opcode, on the other hand, is useless without *jsr* or *jsr_w*, since only these two instructions can create a stack element of type `returnAddress` (and via some *astore* a local variable of that type) to by used by *ret*.

---

I still think that some notice to this effect should have been included in §6.5. Unfortunately, the [Java bug report webpage](http://bugreport.java.com/) hides the *Continue* button if one selects Type: *Bug*, Category: *Java Platform Standard Edition*, Subcategory: *specification*. It states that

> This subcategory is for reporting technical errors and ambiguities in the text of the Java Language Specification and the JVM Specification. It is not the venue to propose new features in the Java language or JVM. Ongoing feature development is carried out in [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/); corresponding enhancements to the Java Language Specification and the JVM Specification are managed through the [Java Community Process](http://www.jcp.org/).

But going through the JCP just to get some clarifying notes added to the descriptions of these three opcodes feels like massive overkill. So I hope that this post here helps those who on their own fail to find an answer in the specification itself.

Comment: Nice work! I have once reported a feature request to Java (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056219/can-javap-show-the-original-source-code-lines-intermingled-with-the-bytecode-lik)(granted, granted, possibly in the wrong place...), and *it doesn't even show up on a public URL without approval from Oracle*, which never happened... :‑/ Like Android, we have to accept Java as it is, a semi-perfect gift from the Gods.

Comment: As an addition, even if `jsr` was mentioned in the Type Checking Instructions, it still was impossible to handle them with the new stack frame based verification, as each branch target *requires* an explicit stack frame, but stack frames have no way of representing a *return address* type in a frame.